# Rails 3.2 using curb gem. error - uninitialized constant LoginController::Curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler, curb

I've installed `curb` gem
1) `gem install curb`
2) included in gemfile `gem 'curb'`
3) in boot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb'
```

But i get an error when i try to use Curl
`http = Curl.post('http://localhost:3000/', data )`
I get an error 
`uninitialized constant LoginController::Curl`

**UPDATE**
In the end i switched to `gem "faraday"`

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` (or `bundle`) after modifying your `Gemfile`? It's not necessary to manually run `gem install curb`, but you do need to run `bundle install` when your `Gemfile` changes to have it update your `Gemfile.lock` file.

Comment: I did run `bundle install`!